# Нужно с помощью wordpress api редактировать пост в питоне

Tags: python, wordpress, api

```
import base64
import requests
import json
from wordpress import API

url="url"
username = "username"
password = "password"
credentials = username + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}
post = {
'title'    : "New post"
'content'  : message
}
responce = requests.post(url, headers=header, json=post)
print(responce)
```

Примерно такой код.
Если она вообще не правильная, можете объяснить как редактировать пост в wordpress.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ и в частности https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/ + https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/application-passwords/

Comment: мне нужно в питоне